# conditions not working (Discordia)

Tags: api, if-statement, lua, conditional-statements, discord

I'm trying to make a bot for discord that generates social security numbers using [Discordia](https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia) and my conditions doesn't seem to work. I tried everything but I can't make it, the function is working properly, but when I put a number higher than 30 it should return an error, but it generates the social security number without returning anything. code below:

```
   if (tonumber(numg)) and (tonumber(numg) >= 0) and (math.floor(tonumber(numg)) == tonumber(numg)) then
    --the function (working well)
    elseif tonumber(numg) > 30 then

      message.channel:send("Muitos CPFs, por favor, insira um número menor")

    else 

      message.channel:send("Insira parâmetros válidos")

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
function foo(numg)
    n = tonumber(numg)

    if n >= 0 and (math.floor(n) == n) then
        print("any positive, natural number")
    elseif n > 30 then     
        print("any real number (with decimal portion) greater than 30")   
    else     
        print("real numbers less than 30")      
    end
end
```

So: any number greater than 30 that is equal to its floor (i.e. it is a natural number, an integer) will enter the first `if` block. It will only enter the `elseif` block if it is not a natural number.

My guess is that is *not* what you want, but that’s for you to decide. This way its a bit clearer what’s going on.

Comment: Better make `n` a local and do something if `n`is nil.